# Cucumber undefined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, rspec-expectations

I'm using `cucumber` with `capybara`

I've got several similar errors.

For step:

```
Then /I should see movies of rating 'PG' or 'R'/ do
  page.body.should match(/<td>PG<\/td>/)
  page.body.should match(/<td>R<\/td>/)
end
```

Cucumber error:

```
undefined method `match' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:...> (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:37:in 
   `/I should see movies of rating 'PG' or 'R'/'
```

For step:

```
Then /I should see an empty table/ do
  page.body.scan(/<tr>/).length.should == 0
end
```

Cucumber error:

```
undefined method `should' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:46:in 
      `/I should see an empty table/'
```

And for step:

```
Then /I should see all of the movies/ do
  Movie.find(:all).length.should page.body.scan(/<tr>/).length
end

undefined method `should' for 10:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:59:in 
    `/I should see all of the movies/'
```

The whole file of steps is [here](https://gist.github.com/2945554)

As you can see these errors are quite similar but I can't understand what cause this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me like you are having problems with the rspec-expectations. Try to add

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
```

to your env.rb and the equivalent to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MiniTest instead of Rspec, try `assert`

i.e.

```
assert page.body.scan(/<tr>/).length == 0, "Expected to not find <tr> in page. "
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative (thought @dabai's solution is probably the best), you can use an assertion instead, like:

```
assert Movie.find(:all).length == page.body.scan(/<tr>/).length
```